# Best approach to listen (watch) a field using react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I would like to update the page state depending on a select field

Here is an example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller, useWatch } from 'react-hook-form';

const MyForm = () => {
  const { control } = useForm();
  const selectedRoom = watch('room', '');

  // You can perform actions based on the selected room
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Example: Log the selected room to the console
    console.log('Selected Room:', selectedRoom);

    // Add any other logic you want to execute based on the room field
  }, [selectedRoom]);

  return (
    <form>
      {/* Room Selection */}
      <div>
        <label>Room:</label>
        <Controller
          name="room"
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({ field }) => (
            <select {...field}>
              <option value="">Select a room</option>
              <option value="room1">Room 1</option>
              <option value="room2">Room 2</option>
              {/* Add more rooms as needed */}
            </select>
          )}
        />
      </div>

      {/* Start Date */}
      <div>
        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <Controller
          name="startDate"
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({ field }) => <input type="date" {...field} />}
        />
      </div>

      {/* End Date */}
      <div>
        <label>End Date:</label>
        <Controller
          name="endDate"
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({ field }) => <input type="date" {...field} />}
        />
      </div>

      {/* Button without onSubmit */}
      <button type="button">Simulate Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

The problem here is if you read the documentation you can find this:

> watch result is optimised for render phase instead of useEffect's
> deps, to detect value update you may want to use an external custom
> hook for value comparison

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch

What can I use? useWatch? the select onChange?
I'm avoiding the onChange because I already created the form controls using Controller and useFormContext
The idea to use react-hook-form is to register the form and control from there, right?